# How Node.js emitter works? Understand passing arguments

Tags: node.js, events

I don't understand how the `function(msg)...` is called with `myEmmiter.emit`.
How does the `.emit('someEvent', ...)` know that the argument `'the event was emitted'` should be passed to `function(msg)...`?
Is there a way to see the `emit` method source?

```
const events = require('events');
var myEmmiter = new events.EventEmitter();

myEmmiter.on('someEvent', function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
});

myEmmiter.emit('someEvent', 'the event was emitted');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation for the `events` module can be found here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js

In abstract, an `EventEmitter` instance maintains an object where the keys are the event names (`someEvent`) and the values are arrays of functions that should be called whenever that event is generated:

```
this.registeredEvents = {
  someEvent : [ handler ]
};
```

To register for an event, you use `emitter.on()/emitter.addListener()`:

```
on(eventName, handler) {
  if (! Array.isArray(this.registeredEvents[eventName])) {
    this.registeredEvents[eventName] = [];
  }
  this.registeredEvents[eventName].push(handler);
}
```

When you call `emitter.emit()`, each handler is called with the argument:

```
emit(eventName, message) {
  (this.registeredEvents[eventName] || []).forEach(handler => handler(message));
}
```